# How to customize Social Traffic with Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, it's easy to view the traffic from Twitter, Facebook or even Youtube. But it's hard to customize some traffic in specific situation, like other social networks that GA can't detect.

I can use JavaScript to detect some customized SNS (which might be not that popular like FB or Twitter) like:

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.includes('newFaceBook') ) {
  ga.setSocial('newFB');
}
```

or

```
if ( window.location.includes('#someOtherSNS=1') ) {
  ga.setSocial('NewSNS');
}
```

I used `ga.setSocial` to say what I want. Now I'd like to know, how could I do this?

Comment: Where did you find `ga.setSocial`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some social network (that GA can't detect) to report **Default Channel Grouping - Social**, navigate to *Admin -> View -> Channel Settings -> Channel Grouping -> Default Channel Grouping -> Social*

and set up additional conditions for social networks you want.
Edit access at the view level is needed.

[image]

Comment: Sounds interesting but it's not able to check useragent string in this way.

Comment: @darkrose1977 What for do you need User Agent?

Comment: as I described in the question, I need the user agent string to know what Social channel it is.

Comment: @darkrose1977 In `User Agent` you'll see Browser or Name of Robot (Google bot etc.). Source is determined by `Referrer`.